# How can I acces Facebook ad information from Adverts Manager with the Ads API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I have several ads in my Facebook Ads-account which are constructed with the Power Editor. For these ads I also make use of custom audiences, I was wondering if it is possible to extract the 13-character Custom Audience ID from the different audiences using the Ads API. I read that you should get your app whitelisted to get access, however, I'm not using an app for my ads as far as I know. The ads are simply created through the Adverts Manager. Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Kind regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

The Custom Audiences API is part of the Facebook Ads API, so even if you are not going to use the app for creating ads, you still need an app that has been whitelisted to allow access to the the API you want.

Typically to apply you will need to speak to a representative at Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for your reaply Paul!